# Newly installed AMD Catalyst Drivers don't show in Catalyst Center

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, amd-catalyst

I downloaded AMD 12.2 Catalyst for my HP DV6 7690M XT graphics card and installed it over the HP one, so that I can switch graphics cards.

After installation, I found out that the Catalyst center is still showing old drivers. How can I assure that my drivers have been updated?

Comment: Did the answer given below work? I am facing a similar peoblem and I need to know if it did.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the ATI drivers using Catalyst install manager then go into device manager and click on display and right click on your graphics card and choose uninstall.  You also have to click the box that says delete or remove driver from system.

Reinstall 12.2 and you should have the latest driver.